# Please help i have got very confused with the if statement below

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement

I want the user to input a number, but if it is below zero I would like to show an error message and then loop round and ask the user for another number. Here is the code I have at the moment.

```
  // this determines what the loop does.
for (int CustPos = 0; CustPos < LineNum; CustPos = CustPos + 1)  
{
   // this asks the user to enter the sales figures
   Console.Write("enter sales figures for" + customer[CustPos] + "  "); 
   // this is user's input is read in and stored.
   sales_figures[CustPos] = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 

   if (sales_figures[CustPos] < MIN_SALES_FIGURE) //True - continue
   {
      Console.WriteLine("");
      Console.WriteLine("entry invalid");
      Console.WriteLine("enter another value");
   }
   else//FALSE -> Go back to start of loop
   {
       Console.WriteLine("");
   }


   //this section displays the cust name, sales figure 70/30.
   Console.WriteLine(" ");
   fee_payable[CustPos] = (sales_figures[CustPos] / 100.0) 
               * licence_fee_in_percent[CustPos];
   Console.WriteLine(customer[CustPos] + 
                 " ----------- " + fee_payable[CustPos]);
   Console.WriteLine("Licence fee to be paid in GBP is :" + 
                 fee_payable[CustPos]);
   seventy_percent_value = ((fee_payable[CustPos] / 10.0) * 7);
   Console.WriteLine("70 percent of this fee is" + 
                  seventy_percent_value);
   thirty_percent_value = ((fee_payable[CustPos] / 10.0) * 3);
   Console.WriteLine("30 percent of this fee is" + 
                   thirty_percent_value);
   Console.WriteLine(" ");
}
```

. Please help all advice will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Comments like `// this determines what the loop does` are completely useless. `// loop over all customers in the document` would be much more useful to a future maintainer.

Comment: To whoever downed this: there's no reason: it's clear enough what it is being asked, and it's a perfectly legitimate question.  Also @Banang, did you ask if this was homework? It could be that Stephen is doing a problem out of a book so he can learn programming on his own.

Comment: @Cpfohl, no, I did not ask Stephen if it was homework, and you are right I should have done that. @Stephen, is this homework? If it is, that's ok, but if not, tell me and I'll remove the homework tag that I put there. Sorry for not asking you before I put it there. For the record, I agree with Cpfohl that this question does not deserve a down-vote, it's clear enough and better than a lot of first-time style questions here at SO.

Comment: @Banang: Wow! Thanks so much for not being upset. +1.

Comment: @Cpfohl: there is no reason I should be upset, is there? You were completely right in questioning my re-tag.

Comment: I've questioned things before and gotten snapped at... :) That's all. You were respectful and I appreciated that.

Comment: it is not a homework assignment. so in future could you ask, rather than just presuming the fact and going on to edit the post. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre on the right track, just look at the keyword [Continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

This is the example in the link:

```
using System;
class ContinueTest 
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
        {
            if (i < 9) 
            {
                continue;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: `The continue statement passes control to the next iteration of the enclosing iteration statement in which it appears.`

Comment: That's a *real* example from MSDN? Wow. Just...wow. 88414 employees and this was the best example they could come up with for the use of continue.

Answer (score 3):

I think a do-while loop would be better here, pseudocode:

```
userInput = -1
do
{
    userInput = Console.ReadLine
}
while (userInput <0)
```

Colin E.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (sales_figures[CustPos] < MIN_SALES_FIGURE) //True - Continue                   //FALSE -> Go back to start of loop
```

You don't actually have any code here to make it go back to the start of the loop.

I recommend that you write it all out as pseudocode first, then turn it into code:

```
if (number entered is too low)
    then restart loop
    otherwise carry on
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an if, you'll want a while:

```
while( sales_figure[CustPos] < 0 )
{
    Console.Write("enter sales figures for" + customer[CustPos] + "  ");

    sales_figures[CustPos] = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Which guarantees that it will keep prompting until they enter something greater than zero.

Continue, does **NOT** do what you want it to.  Continue means, "move on and ignore this iteration" which means you'd have an incorrect value for that customer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a WHILE loop in combination with your IF:

```
continueflag = 0;
while (continueflag == 0)
{
    sales_figures[CustPos] = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("");

    if (sales_figures[CustPos] >= MIN_SALES_FIGURE) {
        Console.WriteLine("entry invalid");
        Console.WriteLine("enter another value");
    } else continueflag = 1;
}
```

Comment: Continue is a keyword.  You shouldn't use it as a variable name.

Comment: coontinue wasnt set as a variable it was just a comment reminding me that if its true it continues.